# Arbuh mayoys (400) mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series

B"H

It's well known that every number has some kind of significance in the Torah, so what then does the number 400 (represented by the hebrew letter Tuff) have in the Torah?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking up, Jacob saw Esau coming, accompanied by **four hundred men**. [Genesis 33:1]

Answer (score 2):

God told Abram: Know well that your offspring shall be strangers in a land not theirs, and they shall be enslaved and oppressed **four hundred years**. [Genesis 15:13]

Answer (score 2):

[Bereishis 23:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.23.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) - Avraham purchased the cave of Machpelah from Ephron for 400 silver pieces.

Answer (score 2):

In [Mishnah Bava Kammah 8:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Bava_Kamma.8.6?ven=Mishnah_Yomit_by_Dr._Joshua_Kulp&lang=bi) it details a series of 400 zuz penalties for doing certain damages:

> הַתּוֹקֵעַ לַחֲבֵרוֹ, נוֹתֵן לוֹ סֶלַע. רַבִּי יְהוּדָה אוֹמֵר מִשּׁוּם רַבִּי יוֹסֵי הַגְּלִילִי, מָנֶה. סְטָרוֹ, נוֹתֵן לוֹ מָאתַיִם זוּז. לְאַחַר יָדוֹ, נוֹתֵן לוֹ **אַרְבַּע מֵאוֹת זוּז**. צָרַם בְּאָזְנוֹ, תָּלַשׁ בִּשְׂעָרוֹ, רָקַק וְהִגִּיעַ בּוֹ רֻקּוֹ, הֶעֱבִיר טַלִּיתוֹ מִמֶּנּוּ, פָּרַע רֹאשׁ הָאִשָּׁה בַּשּׁוּק, נוֹתֵן **אַרְבַּע מֵאוֹת זוּז**. זֶה הַכְּלָל הַכֹּל לְפִי כְבוֹדוֹ. אָמַר רַבִּי עֲקִיבָא, אֲפִילוּ עֲנִיִּים שֶׁבְּיִשְׂרָאֵל, רוֹאִין אוֹתָם כְּאִלּוּ הֵם בְּנֵי חוֹרִין שֶׁיָּרְדוּ מִנִּכְסֵיהֶם, שֶׁהֵם בְּנֵי אַבְרָהָם, יִצְחָק וְיַעֲקֹב. וּמַעֲשֶׂה בְּאֶחָד שֶׁפָּרַע רֹאשׁ הָאִשָּׁה בַּשּׁוּק, בָּאת לִפְנֵי רַבִּי עֲקִיבָא, וְחִיְּבוֹ לִתֵּן לָהּ אַרְבַּע מֵאוֹת זוּז. אָמַר לוֹ רַבִּי, תֶּן לִי זְמַן. וְנָתַן לוֹ זְמַן. שְׁמָרָהּ עוֹמֶדֶת עַל פֶּתַח חֲצֵרָהּ וְשָׁבַר אֶת הַכַּד בְּפָנֶיהָ, וּבוֹ כְּאִסָּר שֶׁמֶן. גִּלְּתָה אֶת רֹאשָׁהּ, וְהָיְתָה מְטַפַּחַת וּמַנַּחַת יָדָהּ עַל רֹאשָׁהּ. הֶעֱמִיד עָלֶיהָ עֵדִים, וּבָא לִפְנֵי רַבִּי עֲקִיבָא. אָמַר לוֹ, רַבִּי, לָזוֹ אֲנִי נוֹתֵן אַרְבַּע מֵאוֹת זוּז. אָמַר לוֹ, לֹא אָמַרְתָּ כְּלוּם. הַחוֹבֵל בְּעַצְמוֹ, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵינוֹ רַשַּׁאי, פָּטוּר. אֲחֵרִים שֶׁחָבְלוּ בּוֹ, חַיָּבִין. וְהַקּוֹצֵץ נְטִיעוֹתָיו, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵינוֹ רַשַּׁאי, פָּטוּר. אֲחֵרִים שֶׁקָּצְצוּ אֶת נְטִיעוֹתָיו, חַיָּבִים:
>
> If a man boxed the ear of his fellow, he must pay him a sela (four. Rabbi Judah says in the name of Rabbi Yose the Galilean: “A maneh (one hundred.” If he slapped him he must pay 200 zuz. **If with the back of his hand, he must pay him 400 zuz**. **If he tore at his ear, plucked out his hair, spat at him and his spit touched him, or pulled his cloak from off him, or loosed a woman’s hair in the street, he must pay 400 zuz**. This is the general rule: all is in accordance with the person’s honor. Rabbi Akiva said: “Even the poor in Israel are regarded as free people who have lost their possessions, for they are the children of Abraham, Isaac and Jacob. It once happened that a man unloosed a woman’s hair in the street and she came before Rabbi Akiva and he condemned him to pay her 400 zuz. He said, “Rabbi, give me time”. And he gave him time. He caught her standing at the entrance to her courtyard, and he broke a jug of one issar’s worth of oil in front of her. She unloosed her hair and scooped up the oil in her hand and laid her hand on her head. He had set up witnesses up against her and he came before Rabbi Akiva and said to him, “Rabbi, should I give one such as this 400 zuz?” He answered, “You have said nothing.” If a man injures himself, even though he has no right to do so, is not liable. But others who injure him are liable. If a man cuts down his own saplings, even though he has no right to do so, is not liable. But, if others cut them down, they are liable.

Answer (score 2):

Refer to [Megillah 3a](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.3a.4?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&lang=bi) where it notes the impact of the revelation of the Aramaic translation of the Torah:

> R' Yirmiyahu (and some say R' Chiyah bar Abba) also taught: The Aramaic translation of the Torah was revealed by Onkelos the Convert, which he received from R. Eliezer and R. Yehoshua. The Aramaic translation of the Prophets was revealed by Yonatan ben Uziel, which he received from Chagai, Zechariah, and Malachi. **When he revealed it, the land of Israel shook an area of 400 parsah**. A voice from heaven called out: "Who is this who is revealing my secrets to the sons of man?" (Sefaria translation)

Answer (score 2):

Yishai, father of David, lived for 400 years, Rashi Bereishis 47:29

Answer (score 1):

The land of Israel measures 400 parsos long. Refer to [Chizkuni on Devarim 19:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Chizkuni%2C_Deuteronomy.19.3.2?ven=Sefaria_Community_Translation&lang=bi):

Answer (score 0):

B"H

This may be kabbalistically related to the four hundred men as well, but Avraham acquired the cave of machpayluh for *four hundred silver shekels* (beginning of chayeii Sarah), which says in chassidus/kabbalah (see Torah Ohr there, also at end of vayeira), that they alude to "four hundred worlds of delight", that the righteous experience in general (I think mainly in gawn Aydin (garden of eden) mostly but also partially in this world) because the word "silver" (kesef) is related to the word in the holy tongue for "delight" (kisoof, the term for the worlds in aramaic is "the worlds of kisoofeem")

Blessings and success